# Set timeout for phantomjs executed in php

Tags: javascript, php, phantomjs

I am gathering a lot of webpages by phantomjs like this:

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

var system = require('system');
var args = system.args;
var url=args[1];

page.open(url, function(status) {
    console.log(page.content);
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Here is the code which executes the phantom:

```
exec ('phantomjs ' . $phantom_script. ' '.$in,$out);
```

This exec is part of a big for, and sometime it stops executing the phantom. My queston is: is there a possible solution to set timeout for this `exec`?

something like:

```
setTimeout(x);
exec ('phantomjs ' . $phantom_script. ' '.$in,$out);
if(timeout){
    echo "error\n";
}
else{
    echo "success\n";
}
```

Comment: The setTimeout goes in the javascript, not the php.

Comment: @pguardiario OP knows that,  this is obviously a concept code, he wants a similar concept in PHP.

Comment: Well I would not mind, if the timeout was in javascript as long as it will work. But javascript seems to be less understandable for me.

Comment: @Vavlioff - I don't think OP did know that, and anyway, not being asynchronous, there's no PHP analog.

Comment: I did know that but the code I found with many callbacks was not much  understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I figured it out. I timeout the phantomjs in javascript and not in php but it works and that is what I need.

here is the code of phantom:

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

var system = require('system');
var args = system.args;
var url=args[1];

page.settings.resourceTimeout = 10000;   //wait 10 seconds

page.onResourceTimeout = function(e) {
    console.log(false);
    phantom.exit(1);
};

page.open(url, function(status) {
    console.log(page.content);
    phantom.exit();
});
```